# Error in sending mail in java/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send `email` using `java`. But I face error like below

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified

Why am I getting this error when I have passed the correct email-id and password for authentication?

This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestMail
 */
@WebServlet("/TestMail")
public class TestMail extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public TestMail() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        todo(request,response);

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        todo(request,response);

    }

    private void todo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.post","587");



        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                "testing@gmail.com", "testing123");
                            }
                });

        Message message=new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("testing@gmail.com","hello"));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("testing@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Email");
        message.setText("hello this is testing mail \n \n Congrets");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: my error image]

Comment: It's a common mistake, as described in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: okk it's work now thank you @Bill Shannon

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail Authenticator is found in the javax.mail package and is different from the java.net class of the same name. The two don't share the same Authenticator as the JavaMail API works with Java 1.1, which didn't have the java.net variety.

Refer this :
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0538.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Please use proper jar files for POP3 emails:

```
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.activation.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
```

2) And then build your message:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host",                 <mail_server>);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port",                 <port>);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user",                 <user>);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password",             <pw>);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth",                 <logon>);
    props.put("mail.from",                      <from>);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom();
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,  <email_to>);
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,  <email_cc>);
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, <email_bcc>);
        msg.setSubject(x_subject, Globals.q_UNICODE_MAIL);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", x_from);
  //
  //<build your Multipart message>
  //
```

3) Finally, connect and send:

```
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        if ( <logon_required> ) {
             transport.connect(<mail_server>, <user>, <pw>);
        }
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```